# UI Component: position custom split button?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, custom-button

*Magento 2.3.0*

I've added an **split** button to admin product edit page with this code ...

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="translate" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Button\Action"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
</form>
```

... the block class with this method ...

```
public function getButtonData()
{
    return [
        'label' => __('Label'),
        'options' => $this->getOptions(),
        'class_name' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Control\Container::SPLIT_BUTTON,
        'class' => 'secondary',
        'button_class' => 'secondary'
    ];
}
```

This correctly adds a split button, but as first right button. If I've understood DevDocs right, button should be ordered by "priority" (primary, secondary, ...), but is doesn't work here.

Any ideas how to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Magento button has a property called **sort_order** to set the priority of the buttons. In your case, you should add this property in getButtonData() function. Example: I will set **sort_order=1000**

```
public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Translate'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getUrl('*/*/')),
            'class' => 'action-primary',
            'sort_order' => 1000
        ];
```

}
The new button will be shown after Add Attribute button like this:
[image]

Change sort_order to 10, the new button will be shown before Add Attribute button:
[image]

If this solves your issue, please give me a vote

Thanks

Comment: TXH, i kown about `sort_order`, but a) it doesnt work correctly with split buttons and b) as said - if i got DevDocs right, it should grouped by level "primary" / "seondary" ...

Comment: primary and secondary are the class name of these buttons, it used to group buttons and style. If you want to set the priority, you should use sort_order

Comment: Nope, `sort_order` has no effect for split button. Tried with 1 and 1000 and its always first. Please try with this line added `'class_name' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Control\Container::SPLIT_BUTTON,`.

Comment: WTH ... I say it does not work and someone votes up ....

Comment: I think they see my effort and kindness so they gave me a vote. Someone can be faced an analog issue like you.

Comment: No problem with this, but answers should be upvoted for solving issues :) However, thanks for your effort.

Comment: This is the second time I try to support you find your issue. Vote only for encouraging me to continue support everyone has the issues with Magento2.

Comment: Please check tooltip for up/down arrows ... answer is/isnt useful? U/D. It's not about effort, people visite SE to find solutions, not answers with plenty effort.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative `sort_order` value. like `-100`

```
public function getButtonData(): array
{
    if (!count($this->getEnabledWebsites())) {
        return [];
    }

    return [
        'class_name' => SplitButton::class,
        'class' => 'primary',
        'label' => __('Shop For Guest'),
        'sort_order' => -100,
        'options' => $this->getOptions()
    ];
}
```

[image]